# Len() not working...how to count elements in a list in python

Tags: python, list

I have the written the code below, it's not ready yet but I ran into problems when testing it. The goal is to check whether or not numbers 1 to 9 appear more than once in one single row:

```
    def rivi_oikein(sudoku: list, rivi_nro: int):
    unique_list = [] #4
    row = sudoku[rivi_nro]
    zeros = row.count(0) #6
    others = len(unique_list)
    for i in row:
        if i not in unique_list:
            unique_list.append(i)
    
    print(unique_list) # prints -> [9, 0, 8, 3]
    print(row) # prints -> [9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0]
    print(others) # prints ->  0
    print(zeros) # prints -> 6
   
if __name__ == "__main__":

    sudoku = [
    [9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 7, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4],
    [2, 9, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 7, 3, 0, 5, 6, 0],
    [7, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 4, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 7, 8, 0, 3, 9, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3],
    [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
    ]

    print(rivi_oikein(sudoku, 0))




enter code here
```

What confuses me is the "print(others) as it's supposed to be "len(unique_list)" which contains 4 numbers. Why the len()  isn't working?

Sorry for the bad indent. I can't figure out how to copy+paste it correctly.

Comment: You assign `others` *before*  you add anything into `unique_list`. Why did you expect `others` to be updated automatically?

Comment: Hi :) Please make sure to stick to the principles of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); in particular, *minimal*. Pasting a large chunk of code in which only a small part of the lines is actually relevant just makes the question messier, and less helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `others = len(unique_list)`, the length of `unique_list` really *is* 0. This syntax doesn't forever bind the variable `others` to the length of `unique_list`; it just grabs whatever that length is at the moment of running that instruction, and stores it (as a number, completely independent from `unique_list` henceforth) within `others`, so that's what you're seeing.

You could, for instance, `print(len(unique_list))` instead if what you want is to find the length of it at the time of printing; or, if you do want to store it as well, assign that value when it makes sense (i.e, when the list is at the state you wish to sample):

```
others = len(unique_list)
print(others)
```

or some such thing.